# Elasticsearch: restart node after java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

One of my ES nodes has failed because of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. Here is the full stack trace from the logs:

```
    [2020-09-18T04:25:04,215][WARN ][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [search1] [[my_index_4][0]] failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [my_index_4][0], node[cm_76wfGRFm9nbPR1mJxTQ], [R], s[STARTED], a[id=BUpviwHxQK2qC3GrELC2Hw]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [search3][X.X.X.179:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]] disconnected
[2020-09-18T04:25:04,215][WARN ][o.e.c.a.s.ShardStateAction] [search1] [my_index_4][0] received shard failed for shard id [[my_index_4][0]], allocation id [BUpviwHxQK2qC3GrELC2Hw], primary term [2], message [failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [my_index_4][0], node[cm_76wfGRFm9nbPR1mJxTQ], [R], s[STARTED], a[id=BUpviwHxQK2qC3GrELC2Hw]], failure [NodeDisconnectedException[[search3][X.X.X.179:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]] disconnected]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [search3][X.X.X.179:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]] disconnected
[2020-09-18T04:25:04,215][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.c.n.i.TransportNodesInfoAction] [search1] failed to execute on node [cm_76wfGRFm9nbPR1mJxTQ]
org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [search3][X.X.X.179:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/info[n]] disconnected
[2020-09-18T04:25:04,219][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [search1] Cluster health status changed from [GREEN] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards failed [[my_index_4][0]] ...]).
[2020-09-18T04:25:05,450][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [search1] [gc][11099506] overhead, spent [605ms] collecting in the last [1.4s]
[2020-09-18T04:25:05,453][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [search1] fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[search1][search][T#5]], exiting
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.composite.CompositeValuesSource$GlobalOrdinalValuesSource.<init>(CompositeValuesSource.java:137) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.composite.CompositeValuesSource.wrapGlobalOrdinals(CompositeValuesSource.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.composite.CompositeValuesComparator.<init>(CompositeValuesComparator.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.composite.CompositeAggregator.<init>(CompositeAggregator.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.composite.CompositeAggregationFactory.createInternal(CompositeAggregationFactory.java:52) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactory.create(AggregatorFactory.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories.createTopLevelAggregators(AggregatorFactories.java:216) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationPhase.preProcess(AggregationPhase.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$loadIntoContext$14(IndicesService.java:1133) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService$$Lambda$2241/341562582.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$cacheShardLevelResult$15(IndicesService.java:1186) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService$$Lambda$2242/1286052129.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:160) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:143) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.cache.Cache.computeIfAbsent(Cache.java:412) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache.getOrCompute(IndicesRequestCache.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.cacheShardLevelResult(IndicesService.java:1192) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.loadIntoContext(IndicesService.java:1132) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:305) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:340) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:316) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:312) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$3.doRun(SearchService.java:1002) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:672) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Because of the exception above, I am getting `master_not_discovered_exception` when I am hitting  any of ES APIs.

**Question**: Can anyone tell me the next steps that I should perform to put Elasticsearch back to normal state? Is there a way to restart disconnected node?

Comment: this error means that whatever the process - is now dead (I am not very familiar with cassandra), so it seems you need to start this process again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me briefly explains what might have caused this issue:

1. As mentioned in the logs, you seems to be running costly aggregation, which are in general memory intensive and known to consume a lot of memory, which your Garbage collection(GC) was not able to reclaim, and eventually your application(ES) ran out of memory and got killed.
2. Apart from costly aggregations which is shown in the logs, high memory consumption can also be caused by heavy searches and indexing request, so please have a look at this node's both search and index slow logs, [refer ES slow logs for more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html)

**Now coming to resolution part**

This ES node is dead, which is causing `master_not_discovered_exception` hence its important to bring restart this node again and see if this exception goes.

**Prevention of OOM exception**

1. You should properly [configure the circuit breaker available in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/circuit-breaker.html) and if possible upgrade to [ES 7.X which has better circuit breakers based on real-memory](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-node-resiliency-with-the-real-memory-circuit-breaker)
2. Improve ES indexing and search performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I was playing with composite aggregation size parameter. I set its value to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and according to stack trace, exception was thrown while initialization of agg values array `this.values = new long[size];`, here the `size` param is taken from the query

Comment: @I.Domshchikov glad to hear that my answer was helpful, I see in your answer you mentioned abt your next steps and waiting for your update

Comment: QQ for u, related to ES availability under high load cause by my app. My ES heap settings are `-Xms1g` `-Xmx1g`. My App uses composite query to fetch unique filters values, to allow users to filter `Foo` entities (by city, name...).  Usually, there are 3 filters available, therefore app sends 3 composite queries in parallel to get the unique values. For each filter I want to retrieve all its unique values, and because I don't know how many of them exists in advance, I am setting `size` param equals to `Foo` entities count (7-10k). Do you think I may face the `OutOfMemoryError` again?

Comment: @I.Domshchikov 1GB heap for ES is really less and you want to use it for aggregations and huge size param causes more memory consumption so you might get again OOM error

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` was caused by running the composite aggregation query for which I set the `size` parameter to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
{
    "size": 0,

    "aggregations": {
        "myParam.keyword": {
            "composite": {
                "size": 2147483647,
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "myParam.keyword": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "myParam.keyword",
                                "order": "asc"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to stack trace, the error occurred while initialization of aggregation values array `CompositeValuesSource.java:137`:

```
GlobalOrdinalValuesSource(ValuesSource.Bytes.WithOrdinals vs, int size, int reverseMul) {
    super(vs, size, reverseMul);
    this.values = new long[size];
}
```

Here, the `size` parameter is coming from the query.

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965634/5284890 confirms the root cause.

My next step was stopping and running Elasticsearcch again using the following commands

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

My following steps will be to check suggested circuit breaker in ES article mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965634/5284890.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, working on it right now. I increased the heap size to 3Gb, and also refactor the app logic that builds composite agg query to use pagination (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination) - which is designed to cover the case when I don't know number of elements to be returned in advance.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, sorry for delayed answer. So far, we only did upgrade of ES cluster. We have 3 nodes in it. Each node jvm heap was increased to 16GB. We followed this rules to increase it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html. After that the load test was performed, and the cluster was able to handle the required load. Though, we haven't updated ES yet, the decision is to do it later. Once it will be done, I will work on circuit breaker stuff. Thanks for you help and support with solving this issue.

Comment: No worries, glad to hear back from you :)